# 1695 Baptism at sea?

Tags: baptism-records, baptism-practices

My great(5)-grandfather Daniel Cooper Sr. was (supposedly) born at sea, the story told in Littell (First Settlers of the Passaic Valley) is commonly repeated:

[image: Littell, p. 90]

But if this actually happened (there are some family historians who think he was born in New York), what would a good God-fearing member of the Reformed Dutch Church do?  Would the child be baptised ASAP upon his arrival?  Or is it like marriages, where the ship's captain can take care of rites in a pinch?

Comment: Having one of these ("born at sea") in my tree, I have been informed more than once that this is a common euphemism for "Illegitimate".